# WebBrowser Control C# get ref="stylesheet" innerHtml / value

Tags: c#-4.0, webbrowser-control

I am working on semi-automated website-dumps with webBrowser control.
Is there a way to access the content of linked style sheets?

Example:

```
<link href="http://somewhere.com/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I know I could load the style.css again with a WebClient (would require to manage absolute/relative paths though), but it would be much better if I could get it somehow from the WebBrowser control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Albeit linked, the stylesheets are available via DOM (i.e., via webBrowser.Document).
In JavaScript you could access them like this:

```
alert(document.styleSheets[0].rules[0].selectorText)
```

Just translate that to C#.

Comment: not exactly what I was looking for, but at least I can access it by invoking JavaScript. document.styleSheet[0].cssText does the trick. Seems to be an IE only option though.

Comment: It is an IE only option indeed, but thought you were using WebBrowser control for loading websites, which is IE.